# Meaning and correctness of "he was more understanding of her than of any of the others"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What does the following sentence mean? Is it grammatically correct?

> He was more understanding of her than of any of the others.

Comment: It is grammatical. What part of the sentence troubles you?

Comment: I mean can I say _I am understanding of you_ ?

Comment: @rahul: yes, you can - here, _understanding_ is an adjective, describing the subject as _having and/or displaying that they understand something or someone_.

Comment: Hi @oerkelens it would be so nice of you if you could explain me how **understanding** is used as an adjective in the sentence.

Comment: He is understanding. You can parse it in the same way as "The ball is blue". _Understanding_ is used as an adjective in the same way _blue_ is used as an adjective.

Answer (score 6):

> He was more understanding of her than of any of the others.

The sentence is grammatical, and means that *he* showed understanding of *her*, but there are other people involved as well, and he does not show as much understanding of *them*.

Some confusion may arise because in the second part of the sentence, a part is left out - consider the "full" form:

> He was more understanding of her than *he was understanding* of any of the others.

The sentence structure is comparable to the structure of this sentence:

> I received more letters from John than I received from any of my other friends.

In the same way as in your original sentence, I can leave out the repeated part:

> I received more letters from John than from any of my other friends.

---

As to the ambiguity mentioned in the comments, I think that would be there if your sentence would have left out more than just the repeated verb: you can also leave out the repeated preposition:

> He was more understanding of her than any of the others.

In this case, it can *also* mean that *the others* were less understanding of her. In the same way I can also give my example sentence a double meaning:

> I received more letters from John than any of my friends.

Now, I may have received more letters than my friends received from John.

Comment: Also, you failed to note the ambiguity inherent in the sentence: was he more understanding of her than he was of the others; or was he more understanding of her than the others were?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That ambiguity I did not mention, as it is not there. If the second _of_ would have been omitted, I agree the sentence would be ambiguous.

Comment: Oops, you're right—I'd read right over the second _of_, didn't register at all. Never mind, then!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think this ambiguity _does_ play up in similar sentences, so I added it to my answer as well :)

Comment: @Kris: That was concluded already. But in many cases, an author can opt to leave elide the preposition as well, and as is proven by  Janus Bahs Jacquet's original comment, even when it isn't, the elision is so common that it can be assumed. And _if_ the the preposition is elided, the sentence _does_ become ambiguous :)

Comment: @Kris: Everybody agrees that there is no ambiguity, there is no need to keep repeating it. However, the preposition _is_ often elided in sentences like this, so your statement is simply false. I agree that it might not be best practice - but it _does_ happen, and it happens often.

Comment: @Kris Yes, that’s basically what you said. You said, “You never elide anything if it causes ambiguity”. Eliding the preposition here causes ambiguity, so your statement as applied to this sentence is that the preposition is never elided. This is, oerkelens said, simply false.